# Android Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, okhttp

I am using okhttp Retrofit in my Android App to make network requests. On one of the requests I get this error:

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

I see a 201 response in the logs but Retrofit throws this error. Below is my code.

```
signup(signupParams, new Callback<Member>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Member member, Response response) {
                if (member != null) {
                    UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount(member);
                    userAccount.save();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError re) {
                BusProvider.post(new SignupFailedEvent(re, email));
            }
        });
```

signupParams value is --

```
{"emailAddress":"test@gmail.com","password":"tester123","userSource":"APH"}
```

I have tested this json with jsonLint and it is a valid json. And this is my Member Class which should be the response ideally.

```
public class Member {
    public String emailAddress;
    public String token;
    public long id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

Example of the response should be something like this:

```
{
    "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com",
    "id": 1437811,
    "token": "sdhshdghsdhhsdbcjhbsjdhc",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

Comment: Do you have example JSON of the response? This looks like an issue with deserialising the response from the service.

Comment: @AndrewBreen I added an example of the response.

Comment: Can you confirm that is the response you are getting - turn on logging.Verbose in your Retrofit setup code and see what the request and response looks like directly.

Comment: @AndrewBreen Please check my comment below.

Comment: Did your find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

if you sure the postman work, and the model same as the JSON parameter,

maybe you use the "accept-encoding: gzip" or like that in your request header.

retrofit doesn't work with gzip, remove that from the header.

Answer (score 0):

If the source code that you posted for the Member class is accurate, then you are not getting the response JSON that you think you are.

The error message means that the JSON parser found a String where it expected a complex object.

Since you don't have any complex objects in the Member class, the result probably just isn't valid JSON (it doesn't start with an opening curly bracket).

Try either turning on verbose logging in Retrofit as suggested in one of the comments, or posting the same data to the API using a tool like "Postman", and see what the result actually is.

Comment: I turned on verbose logging and I see that my response is encoded something like this:����������������N�0�ߥ�wd�P��,�&j����@�Q�T\��"#�7�����GDS]��!�i�vRRݣ�4�SͷTp��΄ĝ�P�>VP��(Ag��/%�=��/T\T��6����O�&Y$-ۜ���z�5�L�m�5���6��,:���K��*M]���JM+�T���Ɛ�P�᮰pŔ4��\�o���9&��*C?�:��~G�+��?�'v�~��<�=��L�,�6S�5�S�if�F�{���O�a3���Ǯ���" Does anyone know why is the response like this. For all the other API calls, I see valid JSON response in the logcat.

Comment: Yep! that'd be the problem.
The only person who would know "why" is the owner of the API.

Comment: Can you validate it using a tool like Postman as the answer above says to see if it receives the data as expected? This data looks like it's trying to download a file possibly.

Comment: On Postman, the response works fine and as expected. That is what made me think it is something to do with Retrofit. Same api works fine on our iOS client. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this just the gzip response? How did you add the logger to Retrofit? Also, postman might be sending headers that make the server behave differently. I'd check this too.

Answer (score 0):

This is cause .your respons is not json formated . it may include with string or expected } . to identify this .you have to check with postman and change view type in body as HTML . there you can see full response and you can validate with *https://jsonlint.com/ .  else in the case of Dynamic json . you can use JsonElement as response.